# Model not cloning

Tags: lua, roblox

I grouped parts together as a Model and it's not cloning, here's my code

```
local space = workspace.Space --the model

while wait(1) do
for i = 1, 10, 1 do
        local s = space:Clone()
        s.Parent = workspace
        s:MoveTo(Vector3.new(space.Fl.Position.x+i, space.Fl.Position.y, space.Fl.Position.Z))
        print(i)
        wait()
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am very sure that is because the model or one of the members has the `Archivable` property turned off, try using

```
space.Archivable = true
local s = space:Clone()
space.Archivable = false
```